# Increase three elements by one number in a loop

Tags: php, html

I have three elements (radiobuttons) that each have their own id and classes.

Simply said they are just 1, 2 ,3 but there are more radiobutton groups on one page, I loop them so I need the next group to have 4 5 6 and then 7 8 9.

I've tried to do that with the following code:"

```
$een = 1;
$twee = 2;
$drie = 3;
$getcats = 'SELECT * FROM questioncat WHERE tid = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($gettemplate['id']).'" ORDER BY id';
$getcatscon = $conn->query($getcats);
while($getcats = $getcatscon->fetch_assoc()){
$werkplekinspectie .= '
<label class="categorytitle">'.$getcats['title'].'</label>
<div class="row">';

$getquestions = 'SELECT * from questions WHERE catid = "'.$getcats['id'].'"';
$getquestionscon = $conn->query($getquestions);
while($getquestions = $getquestionscon->fetch_assoc()){
  $werkplekinspectie .= '
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p class="questionclass">'.$getquestions['question'].'</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="container text-right">
        <input type="radio" name="group'.$een.'" id="radio-'.$een.'" value="ok">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-'.$een.'"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group'.$een.'" id="radio-'.$twee.'" value="fout">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-'.$twee.'"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="group'.$een.'" id="radio-'.$drie.'" value="nvt">
        <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-'.$drie.'"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>';
  $een++;
  $twee++;
  $drie++;
}
$werkplekinspectie .= '
</div>';
}
```

But the radiobuttons further down triggers the first group of radio buttons. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about making a counting variable outside of the loop(s) that you're generating the HTML? it'll be less pretty that in each use you will increment it before using it; however you'll be able to control just the one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off with 1 counter and add the relevant offset each time...

```
$offsetID = 1;
```

and then

```
<div class="container text-right">
    <input type="radio" name="group'.$een.'" id="radio-'.$offsetID.'" value="ok">
    <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-'.$een.'"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="group'.$een.'" id="radio-'.($offsetID+1).'" value="fout">
    <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-'.$twee.'"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="group'.$een.'" id="radio-'.($offsetID+2).'" value="nvt">
    <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-'.$drie.'"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
</div>
```

then add 3 to it each time...

```
$offsetID+=3;
```

With your current setup - you should add 3 to each counter rather than just increment them...

```
  $een+=3;
  $twee+=3;
  $drie+=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

My PHP is pretty rusty, but you may be able to pull it off with one counter variable without worrying about incrementing by section...

```
$counter = 0;

$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    print '<h2>'. $value . '</h2>'. $counter++ . ' ' . $counter++ . ' ' . $counter++;
}
```